# BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default in React Typescript app

Tags: reactjs, polyfills, webpack-5, fallback

I am also facing issues with polyfills in Webpack 5. Research shows it is to do with fallbacks which were removed in this version. What do you suggest we do?

ERROR in ./node_modules/@near-js/providers/lib/fetch.js 13:32-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/**/node_modules/@near-js/providers/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
- install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "https": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/bip39-light/index.js 8:16-45
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/**/node_modules/bip39-light'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
- install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 2:16-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/**/node_modules/cipher-base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

I tried a few tricks to use config-overrides.js to customize the configuration, and use the override function from customize-cra package. This did not work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.